# Hide wp_head () only in the homepage

Tags: php, wordpress

I've this code in the header Homepage that find automatically the title page for homepage and the posts how title tag. But I've my personal title tag only in the home page. The source code show 2 title tag in the home.
How can I hide this code in the home?

```
<? php wp_head(); ? >
```

Comment: Hello. You forgot to attach your code.

Answer (score 0):

`is_front_page()` & `is_home()` can't help you ?

Answer (score 0):

i think, you can use the "is_home()" and "is_frontpage()" function, depending on how your frontpage is setted up in theme (static page, blog page...), one of them or using logical and can be necessary.

with this you can do like:

```
<?php 
if( !is_home() && !is_frontpage() ) {
   wp_head();
} else {
   // custom head code
}
?>
```

an other way is using a separate template for home/frontpage (using a frontpage.php/home.php), where you put in your code.

here the difficult for me was to learn how wordpress is using more specific templates and templateparts (like using get_header('home') to use header-home.php instead of header) and with which weight-order they are used.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_home/

https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page

Comment: Here's a guide to template-hierarchy, with that you can do like anything for "personalizing" your theme, like give separate themes for foreign categorys, authors or other criterias.
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Comment: I put this code, hide the automatic title on the homepage, but it does not show the wp_portfolio theme   <pre><?php 
if ( !is_front_page() ) {
    wp_head();
}
?> </pre>